# How to make the data from Firestore in to a global variable in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access a firestore value into a global variable .
when I excute it the out will be ""

Comment: add the related code snippet.

Comment: You cannot simply do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Comment: thank you for reply. but this deocumenttation is not for java